How can make a ScrollView being anchored to the bottom of the screen at all times?
I am trying to not show the background when ever the user scroll so to the bottom that is in red. I need the yellow part to always be touching the bottom when scrolling down. Here is my code.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("Content Above ScrollView")
                    .padding()
                // ScrollView anchored to the bottom of the screen
                ScrollView {
                    // Your ScrollView content
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                            Text("Item \(index)")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
                    .background(.yellow)
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) // Adjust height as per your requirement
            }
            .background(.red)
        }
    }
}


I have tried to use a geometry reader to get the height of the screen and put that as the height of the scroll view.

Currently, your GeometryReader is surrounding the outer VStack, which includes both the text at the top and the ScrollView. You should move it inside the VStack, so that it surrounds the ScrollView only.
Then, in order that the GeometryReader measures the height all the way to the bottom of the screen, it needs to ignore the safe area insets.
Finally, when the ScrollView is pushed up, you see some of the red background showing through from behind. This can be avoided by moving the yellow background to the GeometryReader instead.
Here is the updated example with all changes applied:
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Content Above ScrollView")
            .padding()
        // ScrollView anchored to the bottom of the screen
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                // Your ScrollView content
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                        Text("Item \(index)")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
        .background(.yellow)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    .background(.red)
}


You'll notice that the background remains yellow at the top when the ScrollView is pulled down too. If you want the red to show at the top, but yellow at the botom, then you could keep the yellow background being applied to the inner VStack and use a split red/yellow background behind the GeometryReader instead:
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // ...
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
}
.background {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.red // or Color.clear
        Color.yellow
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea()



That's safeAreaBottom, you need to ignore that spacing from the outer VStack:
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack {
        ...
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom) //<- here
    .background(.red)
}

Output


When you scroll all the way to bottom you still see the red underneath for a second which is what I am trying to avoid.

Hm, IMHO that's expected behavior, I thought you were missing safeAreaBottom part. Btw, I wonder what you want here, since you had a VStack that contains a Text and a ScrollView, however, you need the scroll also outside of its parent VStack, how could it be possible?

There are two issues.

We are trying to override the bottom safe area. There is an easy way to do this: .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
We do not want the yellow background to scroll away, but we are applying it to the content in the scroll view. By definition, scroll view content is scrollable. There is also an easy way to do this: apply the background to the scrollview, not the content.

Solution:
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Content Above ScrollView")
            .padding()
        ScrollView {
            // Content
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
    .background(.red)
    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
}


PS.: Fiddling around with a GeometryReader is not always wrong, but it is very often a sign we are missing a cleaner solution.

With this layout, as the user scrolls down, the red background will remain hidden, and the yellow part will always be touching the bottom of the screen.
struct StackoverflowIssue: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("Content Above ScrollView")
                    .padding()
                
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                            Text("Item \(index)")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                Spacer() // Pushes the yellow background to the bottom
                
                // Yellow background
                Color.yellow
                    .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom) // Adjust for safe area
            }
            .background(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        }
    }
}

